# A generalisation of Sperner families (union-free families)

Tags: co.combinatorics, reference-request

I am interested in a family of sets $C$ with the following property:

- if you take any $k$ distinct subsets $S_1, S_2, \dotsc, S_k \in C$, then $S_1$ is not a subset of $S_2 \cup S_3 \cup \dotso \cup S_k$.

If we have $k = 2$, these are Sperner families.

Has the case $k > 2$ been discussed in the literature?

---

**Edit:** A colleague just pointed out that Jukna (2011): *"Extremal Combinatorics"*, [Section 8.6](http://books.google.com/books?id=NV3Y8vjWo8kC&lpg=PA116&ots=SMcM-jLDn0&pg=PA116&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) briefly discusses these families and gives some references. The book uses the term **union-free families**.

However, it seems that none of the results mentioned in the book address the following corner case that I am mainly interested in:

- The size of the universe $U$ is $O(k)$.
- The size of the family is "non-trivial" (say, $\Omega(k^2)$).

I would like to know more about *positive* results for this case (I do not need an explicit construction; an existential result is fine).

It seems that in the literature, the main focus has been on families that are exponentially large in $|U|$, and to construct such families we need to have a fairly large $|U|$ in comparison with $k$. However, I would like to understand the case of a small $|U|$ (and not necessarily exponentially large $|C|$).

Comment: Union-free family is a different beast entirely! A family is a k-union-free if union of k set is not *equal* to a set in a family. You ask about containment, not equality. What are you really interested in?

Comment: @Boris Bukh: I am interested in containment, not equality. Jukna seems to use the term "union-free family" for this case; see the link in the post. It seems that the term is overloaded, apologies.

Comment: Theorem 8.13 from the book that you linked to seems to answer the question. In your case $n=ck$ and $r=k$, which gives $t=1$ and so $|\mathcal{F}|\leq k+n$. Hence there are no "non-trivial" families. 

Answer (score 2):

For $k=3$ case, there is a result of [Kleitman, Shearer and Sturtevant](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=647989), which gives a bound of $2^{0.7549 n}$ on the size of $C$. In fact they show a similar bound for a $k$-uniform family for any $k$. In a follow-up [paper by Alon](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=829076) an explicit set family of exponential size is constructed.